# Where is Australia's second bitcoin ATM machine?

Tags: bitcoin-atm

Last ABC1's 7:30 ran a balanced Bitcoin story.

http://www.abc.net.au/7.30/content/2013/s3926368.htm

In it they showed a Bitcoin ATM being use in Melbourne.

They also said "One way to buy Bitcoins is using Melbourne's first Bitcoin machine. It's one of just two nationwide".

I haven't been able to google up where the second machine is. Possible places mentioned online are Melbourne (different provider), Sydney and Nimbin.

Anyone know were this second AMT machine is?

Answer (score 1):

The one in Nimbin is definitely a Lamassu, I used it in mid-January this year (2014), and apparently I was his first customer!  You can find them on [coinmap.org](http://coinmap.org)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the reporter, via Twitter.

They commented that "I believe it's in regional NSW, just checking for you".

During the research before asking the question I found one manufacture's blog post that said they had an order for Nimbin (Far North Coast).

The reporter has not yet got back to me with further information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're interested in locating a Bitcoin ATM in Oz, I have just learned (in early 2014) that one will be soon installed in Sydney at co-working place The Workbench, in Ultimo.

It's a pretty cool place too: http://theworkben.ch/

Answer (score 0):

The first Bitcoin ATM is in Melbourne, the second is in Nimbin and there is another one being launched in Sydney tonight. I believe they are all made by Lamassu

Answer (score 0):

Blue bar on chapel st has one.

https://www.getbitcoin.com.au/bitcoin-news/melbournes-chapel-st-gets-new-bitcoin-atm